# Showing a C# WinForms Panel on a Delphi VCL Frame

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi, winapi, vcl

I'm trying to show a panel which is created in a C# WinForms application inside of a Delphi VCL application. I figured it out so that the panel is getting visible inside of the Delphi application. But I also want to get the feature that the C# panel gets automatically resized on size change on the Delphi side(Delphi: alClient, C#-Winform: Dock->Fill). Currently I don't have found a solution to get that working. I have one workaround which I will try but my primary goal is to get the Winforms Panel as a first calss citizen inside of the delphi form.

What I found is that when I use my code the C# panel is shown in the Delphi application but it is not getting registered in the Delphi Components Array therefore Delphi don't know that there is something getting drawn on it.

I'm open for any suggestions and ideas.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Parenttest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetParent(panel1.Handle, (IntPtr)919640);  // the second parameter is the Handle from the delphi form
        }
    }
}
```

Delphi:

```
unit FrmParent;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Caption:=IntToStr(Handle);
end;
```

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: Basically what you are attempting to do won't work. Cross process parenting relationships aren't really supported as per the link above. Whatever the problem is, this isn't likely to be the solution.

Comment: Of course it's not getting registered in the Delphi components (or controls) arrays - it's not a Delphi component or control. Why would you expect anything else?

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the link. I know that this is not the way to go for the masses but for special use cases this is sometimes the way to go.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do, but most probably you need to make your C# form exposed as ActiveX control from a .NET library and then import it in Delphi and use it as ActiveX.

Comment: @KenWhite I know that it is not a VCL component. But I asked if anyone have done this before and managed to get it "registered" there. In the end the VCL components are more or less only winform controls (created using the winapi) and if I get the c# winform component registered as a child I would have to do much less work, because than Delphi would resize it as its child automatically.  If there is no known way I have to manage this by myself this is still perfectly doable but needs more work.

Comment: @White I am not sure what is the whole picture of your project, but that way is bad design for sure. The only "legal" solution close to what you trying to do is ActiveX controls.

Comment: Clearly, you didn't understand the article. This isn't about whether the concepts have widespread utility. It is about the possibility to implement this in a reliable fashion. One of the requirements for this is that you **must** be in control of the code in either thread. Since you are using the VCL on one, and .NET on the other, you aren't even in full control of a single one. You aren't in the special situation where this even possible in theory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to get Delphi handling the foreign handle directly.
So I reworked the sample code from the question as following:
I give the handle from C# to Delphi and "adopt" it in Delphi

```
oldParent := Winapi.Windows.SetParent(CHILD, Panel1.Handle);
```

note the `oldParent` variable. In this I store the parent which owns the Child at first. So when the Delphi application is shutting down I can give the control back to his previous owner. If I don't do this the control will be lost after shutting down the Delphi application.

```
  if(oldParent>0) then begin
    Winapi.Windows.SetParent(CHILD, oldParent);
  end;
```

And I created a event handler for the OnResize event

```
procedure TForm5.Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Winapi.Windows.MoveWindow(CHILD, 0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, true);
end;
```

this "emulates" the behavior of a Delphi component set to alClient.

Worthy to note is indeed, that in the moment when a application "adopt" a foreign handle the event message queues of both applications get chained together. So when your C# application is stuck  in the event loop (blocking operation on a button handler for example) your Delphi application is also stuck and vice versa.